# Update text in Word textbox using R (officer package)

Tags: r, cpu-word, officer

I have a word document filled with text boxes that I would like to update. When I read the document in it appears black because of the text is in text boxes. Is there functionality within OfficeR that I'm missing that could update this text or is there another R package I could use to do this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?